# How to launch python scripts from Windows Shell?

Tags: python, windows, cmd, launch

I would like to launch a python script (file.py)

In order to do this I copied the path of this file in the Python interpreter but I get the error `SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character`

I am beginner and this is the simplest way to launch Python script I found so far... If you have a simpler way I'm open to tips...

Thank you

Here's my Python script:

```
import os
import csv

ACCEPTED_MSG="""
Hi {},

We are thrilled to let you know that you are accepted to our 
programming workshop.

Your coach is {}.

Can't wait to see you there ! 

Thank you,

Workshop Organizers
"""

REJECTED_MSG="""
Hi {},

We are verry sorry to let you know that due to a big number
of applications we couldn't fit you at the workshop this time...

We hope to see you next time.

Thank you, 

Workshop Organizers
"""

path_to_file = "C:/Users/Julien/Downloads/data.csv"

file_exists = os.path.exists(path_to_file)

if file_exists:

    csv_file = open(path_to_file)
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    next(csv_reader)

    for row in csv_reader:
        name, email, accepted, coach, language = row
        print (name, email, accepted, coach, language)

        if accepted =='Yes':
            msg = ACCEPTED_MSG.format(name, coach)
        else:
            msg = REJECTED_MSG.format(name)

            print ("Send e-mail to: {}".format(email))
            print("E-mail content:")
            print (msg)
csv_file.close()
```

Comment: On the command line, run `python file.py`.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to run a script then the syntax is (from your **system__shell, __not** the python shell):

```
$ python path/to/your/script.py
```

If you want to execute from within an existing python shell, you can run (in the python shell):

```
>>> execfile("path/to/your/script.py")
```

Comment: >>> python C:\Users\Julien\Desktop\Python\Python 3\CIFG\Python Basics\Reading Da
ta From CSV.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python C:\Users\Julien\Desktop\Python\Python 3\CIFG\Python Basics\Reading Da
ta From CSV.py
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @JulienBlomme sorry I did not made my point clear: the first syntax is to run a script from your _system_ shell, not from within a python shell.

Answer (score 2):

You can run

```
python<version> <path>
```

Example:

```
Python3 test.py
```

from your error seems like you ran it correctly but the code contains compilation error. Add the code snippet so we can see where is the problem

Comment: I think that the SyntaxError comes from the OP actually trying to use the python shell as a system shell ;)

Comment: As suggested by @bruno desthuillers it might was a sintax error from the wrong  ommand on the pyShell , make perfectly sense , keep us updated ^^

Comment: Does someone know the synthax ? I'm googling this but finding nothing

Comment: Systax for what? Didn&#39;t our answer solved your issue?

Comment: Syntax to launch a script in the Python interpreter shell ... I think I found useful information I'm reading at the moment ...

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to launch a Python script from the Windows console because I haven't added the variable PATH.

So I added the variable path following this YouTube Tutorial: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uXqTw5eO0Mw

Then, I got an error "No such File or directory found" when I was trying to launch the script. That was because I didn't put a SPACE in the path to the script "C: \ ..." instead of "C:\"

Finally, I had a message "python.exe can't find '**main**' module". It was because I needed to save my scripts with the ".py" extension once again.